# How can I get the body of which contains a json

Tags: python, json, post, scrapy

[[image]]

I have tried the Post method, but I still cannot get the json of page 3200.
what I have coded like this:

```
url = u'http://218.57.139.24/pub/jyyc/3200' 
my_data ={u"encrpripid":u"b05bbaf0a62b2e049e005b9467ccbcc6f1d57daf702342a8457db88ba15021f7"}  
yield scrapy.FormRequest(url, method ='POST', formdata = my_data , callback=self.parse)
```

it always says `Redirecting (meta refresh)`

Comment: did you try the url with trailing slash / in the end? I suspect your server might be redirecting the request to 'http://218.57.139.24/pub/jyyc/3200/'  and that's why you get the redirect. you can also validate this by going to the url in a browser and see if / appears at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question seems irrelevant to JSON. `encrpripid` might be given to you from previous request, right? It looks like nonce. Try requesting the previous page to grab a valid (recent) `encrpripid`. [FormRequest.from_response](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.FormRequest.from_response) method might help you.

Comment: thank you.But the encrpripid is one part of home page's url,and I am sure I got the right encrpripid,  FormRequest.from_response method seems to simulate a user login,in my stituation(http://218.57.139.24/pub/gsgsdetail/1100/2e80338bcd261f9f3ec1f75fa41a74bc86e5521766a1b1190a4b047efeeebf02), there is no need to log in the page.

Comment: So you are perfectly sure this `encrpripid` is always the same, right? Try opening and incognito window and repeat the steps you usually do to confirm that `encrpripid` is the same. I can't open this site you're talking about nor reproduce the full process but not matter that you don't login, many websites give you [nonce](http://searchsecurity.techtarget.com/definition/nonce)'s to make sure you don't abuse specially any non-GET requests or to emulate unique sessions.

Comment: I know the problem now, I should get the destination page by using session. Before that I should also get the cookie and the X-crsf-token.at the end, thanks very much.